# Is there a better way to "absorb" the subscript than this \@ifnextchar-hackery?

Tags: macros, subscripts, relation-symbols

In this example document, I want to make a math relation called `R` which gets typeset as `R^X`, but as a math relation. But I want to maybe be able to subscript it. The macro `\myRbad` looks okay without the subscript, but with a subscript it looks wrong because the subscript occurs "after" the superscript instead of being underneath it as it should be. The macro `\myRgood` looks correct in either case. It works by checking whether the next character is `_` and if it is, gobbling the `_` and delegating to another macro which typesets the subscripted version. I wondered though, whether there's a more straightforward way than this to make LaTeX do what I want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\def\myRbad{\mathrel{R^X}}

\makeatletter
\def\@myRgood@#1{\mathrel{R^X_{#1}}}
\def\myRgood{\@ifnextchar_{\expandafter\@myRgood@\@gobble}{\mathrel{R^X}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \myRbad b$

$a \myRbad_Y b$

$a \myRgood b$

$a \myRgood_Y b$

$a R^X_Y b$

$a \mathrel{R^X}_Y b$

$a \mathrel{R^X_Y} b$

\end{document}
```

## Edit:

As a bonus, here is a macro that automates the creation of macros like `\myRgood` (using the improved method shown by @egreg's answer). (You have to `\usepackage{xstring}`.)

```
\makeatletter
\def\makeprocessedmathabsorbsubscript#1#2#3{
   \edef\@themacroname{\string#1}%
   \saveexpandmode%
   \fullexpandarg%
   \StrGobbleLeft{\@themacroname}{1}[\@themacroname]%
   \restoreexpandmode%
   \ifcsname\@themacroname\endcsname%
      \errmessage{The macro "\@themacroname" already exists}%
   \fi%
   \ifcsname @\@themacroname @\endcsname%
      \errmessage{Something strange is happening.
                  I want to create an internal macro for "\@themacroname",
                  but it exists already}%
   \fi%
   \expandafter\def\csname @\@themacroname @\endcsname##1##2{#2{#3_{##2}}}%
   \edef#1{%
      \unexpanded{\@ifnextchar_}%
         {\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname @\@themacroname @\endcsname}}%
         \unexpanded{{#2{#3}}}%
   }
}
\makeatother
```

Now one can write something like:

```
\makeprocessedmathabsorbsubscript{\myRbetter}{\mathrel}{R^X}
```

and the macro `\myRbetter` is provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just define `\@myRgood` with two arguments and use the second one. When you call `\@myRgood` you *know* that `_` follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@myRgood@#1#2{\mathrel{R^X_{#2}}}
\def\myRgood{\@ifnextchar_{\@myRgood@}{\mathrel{R^X}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \myRgood b$

$a \myRgood_Y b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “abstract” version; a trick similar to the one used for commands with optional arguments is used; the inner macro related to `\myRgood` is `\\myRgood` (with a backslash in its name).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newrelation}[2]{% #1 = control sequence, #2 = replacement text
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \def#1{%
    \@ifnextchar_{\csname\string#1\endcsname}{\mathrel{#2}}%
    }%
    \@namedef{\string#1}##1##2{\mathrel{#2_{##2}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newrelation{\myRgood}{R^X}

\begin{document}

$a \myRgood b$

$a \myRgood_Y b$

\end{document}
```

---

A LaTeX3 version of the same

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myRgood}{ }
 {
  \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_math_subscript_token
   { \hammerite_myR:n }
   { \hammerite_myR:n {} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hammerite_myR:n #1
 {
  \mathrel
   {
    R^X
    \tl_if_empty:nF { #1 } { \c_math_subscript_token { #1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a \myRgood b$

$a \myRgood_Y b$

\end{document}
```

Here's the “abstract” version

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newrelation}{mm}
 {% #1 = control sequence, #2 = replacement text
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}
   {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_math_subscript_token
     {
      \hammerite_relation:nn { #2 }
     }
     {
      \hammerite_relation:nn { #2 } { }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \hammerite_relation:nn #1 #2
 {
  \mathrel
   {
    #1
    \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { \c_math_subscript_token { #2 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newrelation{\myRgood}{R^X}

\begin{document}

$a \myRgood b$

$a \myRgood_Y b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, good idea. I will leave this open a while in case anyone suggests an alternative method that is different entirely (e.g. doesn't use `\@ifnextchar`), but I expect I will end up accepting this answer.

Comment: @Hammerite I don't think there's a way to avoid `\@ifnextchar` or equivalent method.